# Why do we have to manually flush() the EntityManager in a extended PersistenceContext?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, ejb, flush

In our J2EE application, we use a EJB-3 stateful bean to allow the front code to create, modify and save persistent entities (managed through JPA-2).

It looks something like this:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateful
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyEntityController implements Serializable
{   
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    private MyEntity current;

    public void create()
    {
        this.current = new MyEntity();
        em.persist(this.current);
    }

    public void load(Long id)
    {
        this.current = em.find(MyEntity.class, id);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save()
    {
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

Very important, to avoid too early commits, only the `save()` method is within a transaction, so if we call `create()`, we insert nothing in the database.

Curiously, in the `save()` method, we have to call `em.flush()` in order to really hit the database. In fact, I tried and found that we can also call `em.isOpen()` or `em.getFlushMode()`, well anything that is "em-related".

I don't understand this point. As `save()` is in a transaction, I thought that at the end of the method, the transaction will be committed, and so the persistent entity manager automatically flushed. Why do I have to manually flush it?

Thanks,
Xavier

Comment: No need to `flush()`. `joinTransaction()` should be enough to save your modifications in your transactional method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be direct and to the metal, there will be no `javax.transaction.Synchronization` objects registered for the EntityManager in question until you actually **use** it *in* a transaction.

We in app-server-land will create one of these objects to do the `flush()` and register it with the `javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` or `javax.transaction.Transaction`.  This can't be done unless there is an active transaction.

That's the long and short of it.

Yes, an app server could very well keep a list of resources it gave the stateful bean and auto-enroll them in every transaction that stateful bean might start or participate in.  The downside of that is you completely lose the ability to decide which things go in which transactions.  Maybe you have a 2 or 3 different transactions to run on different persistence units and are aggregating the work up in your Extended persistence context for a very specific transaction.  It's really a design issue and the app server should leave such decisions to the app itself.

You use it in a transaction and we'll enroll it in the transaction.  That's the basic contract.

Side note, depending on how the underlying EntityManager is handled, *any* persistent call to the EntityManager *may* be enough to cause a complete flush at the end of the transaction.  Certainly, `flush()` is the most direct and clear but a `persist()` or even a `find()` might do it.

Comment: Wooh, it took me some time to fully understand your answer, but now it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Relevant quote from JPA2.1 specification (7.6.4.1 Requirements for Persistence Context Propagation) for the non-propagated
persistence context: `If the entity manager is invoked within a JTA transaction, the persistence context will
be associated with the JTA transaction`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use extended persistence context all operations on managed entities done inside non-transactional methods are queued to be written to the database. Once you call flush() on entity manager within a transaction context all queued changes are written to the database. So in other words, the fact that you have a transactional method doesn't commit the changes itself when method exits (as in CMT), but flushing entity manager actually does. You can find full explanation of this process [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/extended_pc/extended.html)

Comment: I saw this tutorial, but it seems a bit confusing.
It says "This means that any persist, merge, or remove method you call will not actually result in a JDBC execution and thus an update of the database until you manually call EntityManager.flush." Point for you :)

But in the second example, it says that "never() update will be committed at the end of the checkout() method", and this checkout() is empty, without any flush. How can you explain this example?

Also, in Real World JavaEE Patterns by Adam Bien, the GateWay pattern has an empty save method too: http://tinyurl.com/3o96xoh (slide 67).

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no way to know "when" the client is done with the session (extended scope).